# Multiple Instances of a class being overwritten

Tags: python, oop

```
class Player:
    hand = [None]*10
    field = [None]*10
    deck = []

    def __init__(self, deck):
        self.deck = deck

    def setHand(self, hand):
        for i in range(0, len(hand)):
            self.hand[i] = hand[i]

    def setField(self, field):
        for i in range(0, len(field)):
            self.field[i] = field[i]

card1 = Card(1, 0)
card2 = Card(2, 0)
card3 = Card(3, 0)
h = [card1, card2, card3]
f = [card1, card2, card3]
f2 = [card1, card2]

cpu1 = Player(f2)
cpu1.setField(f2)
user1 = Player(h)
user1.setHand(h)
user1.setField(f2)
```

Here my problem is that the `setField` function overwrites both instances of the Player class and I don't know why. I have seen other answers to similar question but I haven't seen what I have done wrong.

Comment: There are lots of problems with the code. What does it mean for both `cpu1` and `user1` to both have `f2` in their `field` attribute? `f2` is the list `[card1, card2]`. Should both players refer to the same cards?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [ask]. For debugging help like this, you need to provide a [mre]. We can figure out what the problem is (`cpu1` and `user1` have the same `hand` and `field`), but it's not obvious from the question. As well, a lot of the code seems to be irrelevant (e.g. `deck` attribute) or repetitive (e.g. `hand` and `field` attributes) and that makes it harder to understand as an example. Also FWIW, you don't need setters in Python, and your setters are really just copiers. You could replace `user1.setHand(h)` with `user1.hand = h.copy()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you're referring to class attribute instead of an instance one. From the code that you've posted, it looks like you have some background in Java, where you can specify some variables in a body of a class, and then refer to them inside various constructors.

It's different in Python though. Whatever you declare in the scope of a class will be shared between instances of the class (especially if it's a mutable data structure - like list).

If you want to have objects that belong to instances only, you need to assign them to "self" inside `__init__` (and naturally, there's no need to have them specified as a class attributes):

```
    def __init__(self, deck):
        self.deck = deck
        self.hand = []
        self.field = []
```

Comment: Thanks this helped me a lot. Guess I still have bad habits from java.